# Why is my KNeighborsRegressor training accuracy decreasing and testing accuracy increasing?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

### Problem Summary

I'm using the [1.88 Million US Wildfires Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/rtatman/188-million-us-wildfires), and using SciKit Learn's KNeighborsRegressor to regress over 'FIRE_SIZE'. I'm receiving the following output and am slightly confused as to why my training accuracies are decreasing and test accuracies are increasing. Looking for some insight here as to what might be happening behind the scenes.

### Output Snippet

```
Test RMSE:  7495.765269614677
Train Accuracy:  0.9995951877448755
Test Accuracy:  0.04561166544992734 

--x--

3-Nearest Neighbor(s) Results:

Test RMSE:  5798.419599886992
Train Accuracy:  0.5157901853607345
Test Accuracy:  0.4288996249038137 

--x--

5-Nearest Neighbor(s) Results:

Test RMSE:  4370.705370544834
Train Accuracy:  0.3818744943896586
Test Accuracy:  0.6755138015850977 

--x--

7-Nearest Neighbor(s) Results:

Test RMSE:  5234.077626536805
Train Accuracy:  0.32715455088444
Test Accuracy:  0.5346566791409124 

--x--

9-Nearest Neighbor(s) Results:

Test RMSE:  4833.210891971975
Train Accuracy:  0.2925369697746403
Test Accuracy:  0.603206401422826 

--x--

11-Nearest Neighbor(s) Results:

Test RMSE:  4662.668487875189
Train Accuracy:  0.27812301457721345
Test Accuracy:  0.6307145104081042 

--x--

13-Nearest Neighbor(s) Results:

Test RMSE:  4475.217632469529
Train Accuracy:  0.2623128334766227
Test Accuracy:  0.659810044524328 

--x--
```

### The Code That The Does Regression

```py
def k_nearest_neighbors(X, y, n):
  
  # Get training and testing splits.

  X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.01, random_state=42)

  # Initialize a LinearRegr model and return scores/results in a dictionary.
  classifier = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=n, n_jobs=-1)
  classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

  y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
  mse_test = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred) # Mean-squared error, test
  
  test_predictions = classifier.predict(X_test) # prediction accuracy, test
  test_score = r2_score(y_test, test_predictions)
  
  train_predictions = classifier.predict(X_train) # prediction accuracy, train
  train_score = r2_score(y_train, train_predictions)

  return {'rmse': sqrt(mse_test), 'train': train_score, 'test': test_score}
```

### The Code That Is Producing Output Snippet

```
for i in range(1, 15, 2):
  print(f'{i}-Nearest Neighbor(s) Results:\n')
  
  X, y = get_prediction_df(conn, cols_with_log, 'FIRE_SIZE', 700000, geohash_precision=2)
  result = k_nearest_neighbors(X, y, i)

  print('Test RMSE: ', result['rmse'])
  print('Train Accuracy: ', result['train'])
  print('Test Accuracy: ', result['test'], '\n')
  print('--x--\n')
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro & **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is discussed in good detail in the below thread,
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59630/test-accuracy-higher-than-training-how-to-interpret

In your case, the train-test split is at 99:1 which is not a recommended split and that could be one reason for the weird results. Go for 90-10 or 80-20 split and use K fold cross validation (with K 10 or 20) and then evaluate your results again.

Doing Cross validation is explained well here:
https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-k-nearest-neighbors-k-nn-model-with-scikit-learn-51209555453a

Comment: I did a cross fold where cv=10 and one where cv=6 as well and received a scores array with negative float values. The article you pointed me towards shows actually better (positive) prediction scores for a model. Any idea what’s causing my negative values?

Comment: So you tried CV=10 for which 'K' value? How much was the mean of the array for CV-10 for Training and Test?

Comment: Negative values for accuracy? @AbdulSohu

Comment: OP's problem is a regression one, where of course the notion of accuracy is meaningless; what they call 'accuracy' here is actually the R^2 score.

Comment: Oh thats right.. A negative R2 indicates the model fit is pretty poor.Please double check the model fit @AbdulSohu

Comment: @sharathnatraj I suppose the only way to check model fit is by calling model.predict(), and the results for that are in the question. I could be wrong here and if so, let me know how else would we check model fit..?

Comment: I dont mean calling model.predict(). Check if you have the right features, that scaling is done properly etc etc, the whole nine yards. Looks like you are directly plugging in the input data without any pre-processing? Checkout the ML preprocessing steps which is where 80% of the hardwork goes into.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though your model is [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) -  as you incorporate more neighbors into the model, you give it the opportunity for the model learn a more and more complex function, but when you check the model against your test set, it doesn't perform as well. That's because your model has begun to learn relationships that aren't present in data that it hasn't trained with (and likely relationships that don't exist). From your results, it seems that overfitting starts to occur between the 3-neighbor and 5-neighbor versions. Perhaps try a 4 neighbor version and see if that produces the best test accuracy overall?

=====

Edit: Based on conversation in the comments, I'm wondering if there is more going on here than just overfitting. Per [the advice on this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/59644/305281)

> I think a first step is to check whether the reported training and test performance are in fact correct.

In situations like this, I will look at a couple of examples where predictions were classified as accurate and more often than not, realize that I made a mistake in my evaluation code that made accurate outcomes look inaccurate and vice versa.

Comment: When overfitting happens, doesnt Training accuracy increase and test accuracy decrease? Meaning, the model is now learning too much from the training set and performs very well but it can't generalize on a test set?

Comment: You raise very good points, thank you for the insight!

Here are the 4 neighbor results.

```4-Nearest Neighbor(s) Results:

Test RMSE:  4524.328935384681
Train Accuracy:  0.42028669564300813
Test Accuracy:  0.6523025460837525```

Do you mind explaining why if the model has learned relationships to an overfit i.e. relationships that don't exist, does it perform so well to new data i.e. the test accuracies?

Comment: checkout - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59630/test-accuracy-higher-than-training-how-to-interpret

Comment: Perform a 10 fold cross validation and check your results again.

Comment: @sharathnatraj haven't been familiarized with CV that much, so what would you recommend? Should I use the vanilla cross_val_score from sklearn or something else in the same library?

Comment: Also, are you doing a 99% train and 1% test split here? Recommended is 90-10 split or 80-20 etc. Any particular reason to do 99:1?

Comment: Good point https://stackoverflow.com/users/13628883/sharathnatraj regarding the inverse from expected results. I'll update my response to include our uncertainty in this answer.

Comment: I have collated my thoughts as a new answer in which I have included a link for CV as well - @AbdulSohu

Comment: @sharathnatraj I iterated the model over different test-train splits and got results that showed testing accuracy decrease beyond 1%, like so: 

```The train-test split: 99.0%-1.0%
Test Accuracy:  0.10377409618872824 

--x--

The train-test split: 97.0%-3.0%
Test Accuracy:  0.07242578496681529 

--x--

The train-test split: 95.0%-5.0%
Test Accuracy:  0.06685114199694864 

--x--

The train-test split: 93.0%-6.999999999999999%
Test Accuracy:  0.06976801027832258 

--x--

The train-test split: 91.0%-8.999999999999998%
Test Accuracy:  0.05168511650970986 
```

Comment: Ideally, for a good model you almost always should see test accuracy only slightly lesser than train accuracy. Only then, can u trust the model.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the image below (taken from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuAFQ.png)):

[image]

This is a generic representation of [bias-variance tradeoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff) in machine learning. The lower of the two curves represents your training error and the upper curve represents testing (or validation) error.

When your model has low complexity, for example low amount of predictors, both errors are high, but as you add more data they both start decreasing but to a certain point. Training error will continue decreasing as the model gets more complex and can continue indefinitely. Simply put, as your add a lot of data to the model, the algorithm can now even better "remember" all the training data and predict it accurately.

But at the same time, the validation error starts increasing due to overfitting - now your model "remembers" the training data very well but this impairs on its ability to make predictions on new data.

Normally, the best model is where testing error curve is at its minimum, a point where you have enough data to account for most of the variance, but not so much that the bias is high.